# Why do bulbs dim when we switch on TV?

Tags: electricity

Why do the bulbs dim for a moment when we switch on equipments like CRT television or water pump?

Comment: Is it a mains powered tv and light bulb system or is the supply from a generator?

Answer (score 1):

A common example of this effect is when a car is started.
In the case of a car the starter motor draws a very large current (100s amps) when it is switched on.
The battery in the car, open circuit voltage $\mathcal{E}$, has an internal resistance $R$ and so when a current $I$ is drawn the voltage across the terminals of the battery will be $\mathcal{E} - IR$.  This is then the voltage across the bulbs and it being lower than the normal voltage $\mathcal{E}$ means that the bulbs are dimmer.

So when you switch on the tv initially takes more than its normal working current and due to the resistance of the mains leads, or other components in the supply line like circuit breakers, the voltage supplied at the power sockets and the light bulbs becomes less resulting in the lights temporarily dimming.

It sounds as thought the lights and the tv are connected to the same mains circuit.  Is it possible to connect the lights or the tv to another circuit so that you could see if that makes any difference.  In the UK the lighting circuits are separated from the ring mains circuits supplying the sockets.

All in all it sounds as though you mains wiring is right on the limit of carrying a safe current and so perhaps should be upgraded to a higher current rating?

Answer (score 0):

If your lights are incandescent bulbs, then the brightness will depend on the voltage at the bulb's terminals.

The voltage of the power line feeding your residence probably is very close to constant, but the voltage feeding your light bulbs may not be the same as the voltage of the power line outside.

Wires and connections between wires have electrical *resistance*.  What that means is, when current flows in a wire, there will be a voltage difference from one end of the wire to the other, and the amount of that difference will be proportional to the amount of current and the amount of resistance.  That fact is known as *Ohm's Law*

$V=IR$

Here $V$ is the conventional symbol for Voltage (measured in Volts), $I$ is the conventional symbol for current (measured in Amperes or Amps), and $R$ is the symbol for resistance (measured in Ohms).

The $V$, for purposes of this discussion is known to electricians and electrical engineers as the Voltage *drop*.  The sum of the Voltage "dropped" by the wire and its connections plus the Voltage delivered to your light bulb must equal the (nearly constant) Voltage that is supplied from the grid.  So, if more Voltage is dropped by wires and connections, then less is available to your light bulb.

Voltage drop is bad.  Therefore, resistance is bad.

But, resistance is inevitable.  It is an intrinsic property of wires and connections.  Thinner wires have more resistance than fatter wires (resistance is inversely proportional to the cross section), and longer wires have more resistance than shorter (resistance is proportional to length).

Poor connections have higher resistance than good ones.

If your lights dim when you turn on some other appliance, it is because the lights and the appliance are sharing part of the same circuit.  Turning on the appliance means that more current must flow in the shared circuit.  More current, according to Ohm, means more Voltage drop, and that means less voltage available to your light bulb.

If the bulb dims only for a moment, that is because the appliance draws a relatively large amount of current only for a moment---a phenomenon sometimes known as *inrush current*, or *surge*.  Electric motors and some kinds of electronic power supply often have a large surge.

---

High resistance in home wiring can be dangerous because of another physical law:

$P=I^2R$

That says that Power ($P$, expressed in Watts) that is "lost" in a wire or a connection is equal to the square of the current times the resistance of the wire or connection.  "Lost" here means, converted to heat.

Poor connections probably are the number one cause of electrical fires.  When a lot of current flows through a high-resistance electrical connection, the wires can get hot enough to ignite the insulation on the wire, and then, nearby flammable building materials.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Switching on a component causes an *inrush current* which causes a voltage drop on the supply.

---

### Proper explanation:

When you turn on a water pump, there is an initial surge of current drawn. For things like motors, this is because the resistance of the coil is quite low, and the current drawn is usually limited by the back e.m.f. of the motor, which depends on the velocity. When the velocity is low, the current is high. This means that while the motor is accelerating, there is a much larger current draw.

For some TVs, when you first turn them on several things may happen - all of which require a significant surge of current. In older systems that use a vacuum tube, there is the need to ramp up the high voltage and the current through the cathode filament; in more modern systems, the low voltage supplies need to be ramped up. In order to have a well regulated supply, you store significant energy (that helps "ride through" the peaks and troughs of demand) with inductors and capacitors; when you first turn the TV on, you need to supply that energy.

Now why does that inrush of current dim the lights? All the current to your home goes through a wire, and in particular it goes through the fuse box (circuit breakers). All these components provide a common resistance to the current; so if the current increases, so does the voltage drop across them.

Now for incandescent bulbs, the light output is a really sensitive function of voltage: with higher voltage comes higher current, so power goes as voltage squared (so a 5% change in voltage results in a 10% change in power); and with more power, the incandescent light will be brighter AND WHITER - the peak of emission moves more towards the blue, and the total amount of light in the visible spectrum changes even faster than the square of the voltage.